# How to find posts with multiple tags using acts_as_taggable_on (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

For example, if I want to find all posts with the tags "Music" and "Beatles", how do I go about doing that? And also, how do I put such a listing of posts in my routes? NOTE: I am using the acts_as_taggable gem to make my tags.

Comment: Have you looked into using  a gem like ransack ?

Comment: I need it for the purposes of having something like a "link_to" to posts with those specific tags. (Although ransack definitely looks like something I can use in the future :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on):

```
# Find users that matches all given tags:
User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :match_all => true)
```

There are a lot of other examples for usage in the documentation if you get stuck.

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'listing of posts in my routes'. If you want to display the users (in the example of above) who have been tagged with these tags, try something like this:

```
# index action controller
@users = User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :match_all => true)

# index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <%= u.name %>
  <%= u.whatever %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**
I think based on your comment on the question that you want to make a link to see all users who have been tagged with your specified tags. In that case, setup a customer route under your users block (in this example).

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :tagged
  end
end
```

Then `<%= link_to 'Tagged', tagged_users_path(tag1: "cool", tag2: "supernice") %>`

Controller `tagged` action:

`@users = User.tagged_with([params[:tag1], params[:tag2]], :match_all => true)`

Then display in your view however you like.